# Bad select block size in div block with contenteditable (Chrome, Safari)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Example:

```css
select {
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  text text text text text
  <select>
    <option>bigbigbigbigbigbigbig</option>
  </select> text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Select block height in Chrome ([Screenshot1](https://habrastorage.org/files/f2f/8e1/448/f2f8e14487d64f509849229fca8ae4de.png)) - bad.

Select block height in Firefox ([Screenshot2](https://habrastorage.org/files/684/a0e/0aa/684a0e0aad7d4c3b8b6ce4d573910073.png)) - good.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it `display:inline-block`?

Comment: SELECT - yes, inline-block (If I apply to select styles display: inline or display:inline-block  - situation does not change ): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pipanchik/d5nbwn8z/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.Wrap up ur text into span and give it vertical-align:top.
DEMO:https://jsfiddle.net/84o8bbb7/

**HTML**

---

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span>text text text text text</span>
  <select>
    <option>bigbigbigbigbigbigbig</option>
    </select><span> text text text text text text text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  max-width: 40px;
}
span{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Jup `vertical-align`is what you need. I updated it to a version that is much more practicable: https://jsfiddle.net/84o8bbb7/1/ Also works in IE10. PS: you not even need `inline-block`.

Comment: Good, it works without the use SPAN block (vertical-align: top to SELECT)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to the problem :

```
select {
  max-width: 40px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

or

```
select {
  max-width: 40px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```